# Rails: can I use a foreign key as a primary key in a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model that uses Devise, and I am creating a Profile model for it.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

As each User will have only one Profile, I thought that it would greatly simplify things by accessing data in a Profile using `current_user.id`. Therefore, I am thinking of skipping the creation of a normal primary key column, and setting the foreign key in my Profiles table as my primary key instead.

This is the migration I am using:

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles, {id: false} do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true, primary_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

I found [an old thread elsewhere](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1357787) that suggests that this breaks Rails convention, but I can't see how there are any downsides to this. Is there anything I'm not seeing that would possibly blow up on me in the future?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, is there any benefit in skipping the creation of the normal primary key?

Comment: Since it is a one-to-one relationship, I was thinking that it would be easier being able to use the value in `current_user.id` to access both User and Profile, with keeping the profile data in a separate model.

Answer (score -2):

The point of a foreign key is to reference the primary key to another table. By not having a primary key, it would just be another column on the table, with no ability to reference a column on the previous table.

i.e.:

```
Table 1: Users

user_id      name    password  post_id
    1        john    pass         1


Table 2: Posts

post_id    post_content
  1        "hello world"
```

If you omitted writing  `post_id` in Table 2, there would be no ability to reference it in table 1. Simply put, you have to have a primary key on a table in order for it to be referenced by another table as a foreign key.

However if you really wanted to avoid having an unnecessary column (primary key), you could "join" (combine) the tables together and omit the need to have a second primary key. In the above example, `post_content` would just go into users. In a one-to-one relationship (which your example is), you would just create one table with all the columns you need in that table.